# how to fill a dict with None for all keys (given in a list) in Python 3.3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

For a `writerow` of a `csv.DictWriter`, I need to fill a (part of a) dictionary to be empty. I found no immediate solution for it. Is there one?

Like with

```
fieldnames = ['first','last']
```

Pseudocode

```
row = fieldnames.fill(None)
```

Result

```
print(row)
['first':None,'last':None]
```

So that

```
destination.writerow(row)
```

results in

```
,
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really a natural for the built-in dict method [fromkeys](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
>>> dict.fromkeys('abcd',None)
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}
>>> dict.fromkeys(['first','last'],None)
{'last': None, 'first': None}
```

No need for a dict comprehension (2.7+) or a list comprehension at all.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with a simple [dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp):

```
{key: None for key in keys}
```

E.g:

```
>>> keys = ["first", "last"]
>>> {key: None for key in keys}
{'last': None, 'first': None}
```

Edit: Looks like `dict.fromkeys()` is the optimal solution:

```
python -m timeit -s "keys = list(range(1000))" "{key: None for key in keys}"
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.4 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "keys = list(range(1000))" "dict.fromkeys(keys)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: So this little loop is no slower than `fromkeys` I overlooked before?

Comment: @László I forgot about ``fromkeys()`` - I imagine there is little to no difference - so I'd recommend you go for whatever is clearer.

Comment: A bit surprising I found no documentation on the `fromkeys` method. But it should get me there. Thanks.

Comment: @László It's there [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys).

Comment: My +1 as I consider a dictionary comprehension more readable and undestandable. Actually, I never needed `.fromkeys()` and I would have to check the doc to understand what it does. (On the other hand, it is quite old method, and other people may prefer it.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> fieldnames = ['first', 'last']
>>> row = dict((h, None) for h in fieldnames)
>>> row
{'last': None, 'first': None}
>>>
```

Comment: Python has dictionary comprehensions now, no need for the generator expression and dict constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to add that this is for pre-2.7 (which is what I've been using for a while - probably time to upgrade :) ).